# Запуск PHP кода из смешаной строки

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте. Пишу что-то вроде редактора с PHP кодом и на пути создания возникла проблема. Код в редакторе выглядит так:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php echo 'Текст'; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Т.е. если я буду запускать этот код в PHP файле просто через `echo`, то часть с php не запустится. Если я буду запускать его через `eval`, то он выдаст ошибку, т.к. это не чистый php код.

Так вот, каким образом можно это запустить, что бы воспринялась и часть с html, и часть с php тоже запустилась?

Comment: Самый простой вариант вставить костыль в виде закрывающего пыхового тега а именно ?> перед началом файла и засунуть в eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту проблему я решил таким образом:

```
$dir = "./_projects/";
mkdir($dir, 0777, true); // Создаю директорию

// Создаю в ней нужный мне файл     
$index = fopen($dir."/index.php", "w");
fwrite($index, $_GET["text"]);
fclose($index);

// Открываю содержимое этого файла
include($dir."/index.php");

rdir($dir); // Удаляю директорию
```

Довольно костыльный вариант, но работает очень неплохо

Comment: Я бы не стал папку в 777 кидать. 755 - стандартные права на директорию, а файлы - 644

Comment: @RomanKozin, а почему не стал?

Comment: Потому, что в данном, Вашем случае - любой сможет удалить папку и контент внутри

Comment: @RomanKozin, ну ладно, изменю, спасибо :)

Comment: У самого проблема с таким была :) Лучше почитайте о разрешениях в Linux и поймете о том, что я Вам тут 'втираю' :) Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: И лучше через chown поставить владельца на папку с x-правами, чем делать папку вседоступной

Comment: @RomanKozin, я этом почти ничего не понимаю. Я по большей части в js шарю. А тут будем разбираться )

Answer (score 1):

Ты не принть контент файла, а принть через file_get_contents документ, где запустится твой редактируемый файл через инклуд. Так и пхп-код выполнится и будет готовый хтмл-код

Comment: С какого перепугу file_get_contents будет выполнять пых?

Comment: Не он его выполнит. Он лишь выведет контент документа, на котором уже будет выполнен этот пых-код. Тобишь допустим: file_get_contents("index.php?file=./test.php")
В index.php - include($_GET['file']);
Это грубый код без проверок, но основная суть тут ясна, надеюсь